# Horizontal pixelated lines on my Laptop LCD screen

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, lcd

This started 3 months ago. At first there was only one horizontal pixelated line on the **top**.
Now, there is one at the **bottom**. Below the bottom line I can see some of the top portion of my display (I know it sounds kind of weird, but I will attach some pics). The lines are rhythmic, they appear for a second and then disappear.

After 3 seconds it comes back. The flickering slows down after sometime. When the screen flickers, there is also a small jump.
It's not a driver error as it even shows in the BIOS and no problem when I hook up an external monitor. I opened the screen and checked the cables. Nothing seems wrong there, I mean no wear and tears, no blackening etc. So is the display cable faulty or my LCD?

Images:
 **Top**

[image]

**Bottom**

[image]

Comment: Looks like your screen is going.  Might not be much you can do besides send it in for repair or replace it.  Thought it sounds like a laptop, so it may not be so easy to replace it.

Comment: What's the model of the (broken) monitor? And you tested the same cable with a different monitor and got different results? If so, I'd conclude it's your monitor.

Comment: @TimmyJim yup its a laptop.

Comment: @Cullub its a laptop monitor. I haven't changes the cables, as there are many, I just took a glance at the main cable and nothing seems wrong.

Comment: Hmm. Sounds like you might be needing a new monitor.  If your laptop is a nice one, it's definitely possible to replace, but it might not be worth it if you got it for $200 at MicroCenter 3 years ago.

Comment: @Cullub You sure the problem will be solved if I replaced the laptop screen?

Comment: Well it's difficult to be sure, but if an external monitor works, that means it's not the graphics card. And if the cables look fine, my first guess would be the screen.

Comment: @Cullub I suppose too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's not a driver error as it even shows in the BIOS

That means it is a hardware issue.  Things to look at.

- Cable that connects motherboard to LCD is pinched, damaged, etc.  Replace this cable.
- Motherboard has sustained liquid damage, possibly near connector where LCD plugs into motherboard.  Cleaning corrosion off with alcohol will help for a while but replacing corroded components is the only permanent solution.
- LCD screen itself is going bad, replace LCD.
- If your laptop is the rare type if an MXM or other removeable graphics card, you can try reseating or replacing it.
- Other issue with motherboard, replace motherboard.

Display cable issues tend to go away or change if the laptop lid is moved, so if this is not happening it is more likely a liquid damage, LCD or motherboard issue.

Comment: Motherboard looks fine. The graphic card is not replaceable. Cable also looks fine. I think LCD is the culprit.

Comment: Will probably be cheaper to try replacing the cable first anyway.  Sometimes they can go bad and not show any visible damage.

Comment: I will try to do that Lawrence, by the way when I opened the laptop, I saw a little liquid on the GPU. Is it heat paste or something is wrong?

Comment: Heat paste will be sticky, typically white or silvery.  Liquid as in water is definitely bad.

Comment: Okay then its not the problem. Because just as you said it was actually pretty sticky.

Comment: I have sent the laptop to repair and its coming today itself. I'll give you an update when it arrives.